# JSON request example for One to Many relationship for creating Resource

Tags: json, spring-data-jpa

I am using SPRING DATA JPA and created the 2 models User and Role where any user can have multiple role i.e one to many relationship.

I have created the model class and while running the spring boot application I am able to create these to tables automatically.

**What Challenge I am facing?** To create an User.

If User and Role both we need to create then I can make a JSON request as below:

```
{  
   "loginCount":5,
   "username":"demouser5",
   "createdAt":null,
   "updatedAt":null,
   "userRoleList":[  
      {  
         "roleName":"demo"
      }
   ]
}
```

I am able to save these object in their table success fully but user_id is not population in the owner side i.e Role and getting the following response:

```
{
    "userId": 1,
    "loginCount": 5,
    "username": "demouser5",
    "createdAt": null,
    "updatedAt": null,
    "userRoleList": [
        {
            "roleID": 1,
            "roleName": "demo",
            "user": null            
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there any way that Save method can handle this automatically or I need to handle it manually in the code by using the role.setUser(user) method at the service level.

Answer (score 0):

I was making a mistake I have change the Many to One mapping to Many to Many and it is working as expected.